# How to I talk in trade chat?

Tags: spiral-knights

Every time I try to say

```
/trade <message>
```

It tells me `You're not in that channel.`

I also tried `/2 <message>` and `/trade 1 <message>`.

`/help trade` was no help.

How do I talk in trade chat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join trade chat before you can talk in it.

Type `/join 2` or `/join trade`, and start spamming your mercantile heart out!~